# State variables not changing

Tags: contract-development

Testing a small piece of code that gets information and the current block, as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract BlockInvestigator {
    address public minerAddress;
    uint public gasPrice;
    uint public balance;
    uint public blockNum;

    function getMiner() payable {
        blockNum = block.number;
        minerAddress = block.coinbase;
        gasPrice = tx.gasprice;
        balance = minerAddress.balance;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to update the state variables of the contract everytime I call getMiner.  However, after deploying the contract and calling getMiner() through a transaction, the state variables do not change (they are all zero from initialization).

Am I doing something wrong, or this a bug?

EDIT: This code works when I remove the variables `balance` and `blockNum` and their assignments within `getMiner()`.

Comment: How much gas are you providing in your transaction?  Try increasing it since this sounds like an Out of Gas exception.

Comment: Do you know how to increase gas when calling from the console? E.g. calling in the console `myInstance.getMiner()` ? Can't seem to find any literature on it. @eth

Comment: @eth Nvm got it and it was an Out of Gas exception, thanks

Comment: Good you got it :)  Perhaps you can post your own answer to help others who may stumble on your question.